# List google cloud compute engine active instance

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm looking to find out all the active resources( like compute engine, gke etc) and the respective zones .
I tried below python code to print that but its printing all zone information wherever compute engine is available , can please someone guide me what functions are available to do so .

```
    compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
    request = compute.instances().aggregatedList(project=project)
    while request is not None:
        response = request.execute()
        for name, instances_scoped_list in response['items'].items():
            pprint((name, instances_scoped_list))
            request = compute.instances().aggregatedList_next(previous_request=request, previous_response=response)
```

Comment: Can you describe more what do you want to achieve? What is an "active resource"?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere,  by "active resources", I  meant the instances which are currently UP and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list all instances  you have in your project,  using the Cloud Console  `gcloud compute instances list` [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/list) or the `instances.list()` [method](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list).

To list all instances in a project in table form, run:

`gcloud compute instances list`

You will get something like :

```
NAME        ZONE           MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP   STATUS
instance-1  us-central1-a  n1-standard-1               10.128.0.44  xx.xx.xxx.xx  RUNNING
instance-2  us-central1-b  n1-standard-1               10.128.0.49  xx.xx.xxx.xx  RUNNING
```

#### Edit1

As you mentioned **aggregatedList()** is the correct one, and to get the information required is necessary to go over the JSON Response Body.

If you need some specific fields you can check the [Response body information](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/aggregatedList#response-body).

Also, you can use this code as a guide, I’m getting all the information from the instances.

```
from pprint import pprint
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
# Project ID for this request.
project = "{Project-ID}"  # TODO: Update placeholder value.
request = service.instances().aggregatedList(project=project)
while request is not None:
    response = request.execute()
    instance = response.get('items', {})
    for instance in instance.values():
      for a in instance.get('instances', []):
          print(str(instance))
    request = service.instances().aggregatedList_next(previous_request=request, previous_response=response)
```

Comment: Thanks Jose for responding to my query . 
I see the above python code asks for zone information and it prints the error without supplying that information . 

The method to list instances across all zones is aggregatedList 

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/aggregatedList
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list

Comment: @Learner I've edited my post based on your last comment.